# Docker centos php5 issues

Tags: docker

I am trying to install php7 on centos using docker. I created my dockerfile like below.

```
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN \
  yum update -y && \
  yum install -y epel-release yum-plugin-ovl && \
  yum install -y gcc wget git zip vixie-cron sendmail rsyslog

# Install Nginx
ADD config/nginx/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
RUN \
  yum install -y nginx

# Install php
RUN \
  rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm && \
  yum install -y yum-utils && \
  yum-config-manager --enable webtatic-archive && \
  yum install -y php70w php70w-devel php70w-pear && \
  ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5
```

When I run the docker file I am getting the below error

```
> [ 6/34] RUN   rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm &&   yum install -y yum-utils &&   yum-config-manager --enable webtatic-archive &&   yum install -y php70w php70w-devel php70w-pear &&   ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5:
#10 1.096 warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RubNcH: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 62e74ca5: NOKEY
#10 1.209 Retrieving https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
#10 1.209 Preparing...                          ########################################
#10 1.210 Updating / installing...
#10 1.210 webtatic-release-7-3                  ########################################
#10 1.310 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
#10 1.346 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
#10 7.700 Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/aarch64/mirrorlist error was
#10 7.700 14: HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
#10 7.707
#10 7.707
```

When I try the same one in my friends laptop all working as expected.
I am using Apple m1 chip.

Comment: Hi, try to update repo list:
use:
https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/x86_64/mirrorlist
insted of:
https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/aarch64/mirrorlist

Comment: @fireman777 - How to do that?